# WHAT "item ->" STANDS FOR IN .setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {})

Tags: java, android

THIS IS THE CODE IN MY ANDROID STUDIO... all it does, it creates snack bar when you click item in toolbar.
My question is, why my teacher on udemy uses "item -> {}" as parameter, when people in .setOnMenuItemClickListener() use new OnMenuItemClickListener()  ???

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Basic Components");
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.simple_snackbar:
                showSimpleSnackBar();
                break;
            case R.id.snackbar_action_callback:
                showSnackBarWithACtionCallback();
                break;
            case R.id.custom_snackbar:
                showSnackBarWithColoredText();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: it just mean the menu item that was clicked

Comment: its a lambda function. It simplifies your code. Take a look at this link for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320007/how-can-i-turn-this-into-a-lambda

Comment: Lambda expression. `item` is passed as a parameter (name) into the function inside `{ }`. This is used in place of a class, usually an anonymous class, matching the parameter for the function `setOnMenuItemClickListener()`

Answer (score 0):

Its a Lamda expression item -> means...

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {})
```

It can be written as :

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new 
MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener(){});
```

Comment: Almost. It's missing the parameter (item)